# Make title of record a link to another module in list view

Tags: symfony1, admin-generator

I am currently using the Symfony admin generator to implement a management web application.

I would like to know if there is a way to add a link on the title section of the generator.yml file.

As example:

```
edit:
        title: Configurations > Officials | "link to another module"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML will accept static HTML quite easily in many tags:

```
edit:    
  title: <a href="/config">Configurations</a> > <a href="/config/officials">Officials</a>
```

Note that while some PHP is also available, it is limited compared to the full symfony stack.